# Can anyone tell me why isn't the query executing in the following php code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Welcome
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
$fn=$_POST['f_name'];
$ln=$_POST['l_name'];
$gen=$_POST['sex'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$em=$_POST['email'];
$un=$_POST['u_name'];
$pd=$_POST['pswd'];
$mb=$_POST['mob'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db')
   or die("Error connecting to database");
$query="INSERT INTO user_details(First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, DOB, Email_Address,
Username, Password, Mobile_No) VALUES                   
('$fn','$ln','$gen','$dob','$em','$un',SHA('$pd'),'$mb')";
echo $gen;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) 
  or die("Error querying the database");

mysqli_close($con);
$name=$fn.' '.$ln;
echo "<b>Welcome $name</b>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do in this code is to take data from an HTML form and store it into a MYSQL database. I even thoroughly checked my database for any type conflicts or any datatype length issues but still I am not getting it.
I don't know why it is showing >> Error quering the database ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysql_error()` will tell you what error mysql is giving you

Comment: I dont see any form ....

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($con,$query)  or die(mysql_error()); to get the exact error.

Comment: Why are you just building a big old nasty query-string like that with mysqli? Just use prepared statements and things get a lot safer and easier.

Comment: @Cylindric easier? how come prepared statements are easier? Can you show the code that is using mysqli prepared statements and being actually shorter than plain query?

Comment: Shorter does not mean easier. Putting all your code in a single big statement does not make it easy. I'm talking about the entire life-cycle here, from first write through to making changes 12 months later. Also, I imagine you're leaving out all the parameter-escaping code from your comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) 
  or die("Error querying the database");
```

to

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) 
  or die($mysqli->error);
```

This will provide you with the exact error message from the server .. [docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using prepared statements with mysqli. It is very simple to do.

Second, you should use `...or die($mysqli->error)` to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

a proper code from someone who have a clue to get the error message in case of failed query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) 
  or trigger_error(mysqli_error($con)." ".$query);
```